# PyAudio 'utf8' error when listing devices

Tags: python, audio, binding, portaudio, pyaudio

When using PyAudio (Portaudio binding) with ASIO+DirectSound support, this code :

```
import pyaudio

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
for i in range(p.get_device_count()):
    print p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
```

... produces this error :

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

**How can we solve this problem ?**

---

The problem may come from "pyaudio.py", line 990, because of an unsucessful utf8 decoding :

```
           return {'index' : index,
                    'structVersion' : device_info.structVersion,
                    'name' : device_info.name,
```

---

This answer here [Special characters in audio devices name : Pyaudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15878370/special-characters-in-audio-devices-name-pyaudio) ("don't use PyAudio") is not satisfactory.

---

**Traceback**

```
...
{'defaultSampleRate': 44100.0, 'defaultLowOutputLatency': 0.0, 'defaultLowInputLatency': 0.12, 'maxInputChannels': 2L, 'structVersion': 2L, 'hostApi': 1L, 'index': 8, 'defaultHighOutputLatency': 0.0, 'maxOutputChannels': 0L, 'name': u'Microphone interne (Conexant 20672 SmartAudio HD)', 'defaultHighInputLatency': 0.24}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\test\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print p.get_device_info_by_index(i)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 977, in get_device_info_by_index
    pa.get_device_info(device_index)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyaudio.py", line 990, in _make_device_info_dictionary
    'name' : device_info.name,
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: Show the full traceback...

Comment: I added the Traceback @Wooble

Comment: The traceback doesn't match your code, but the error does look internal to pyaudio. Have you tried filing a bug report with them?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted a traceback coming from another file where I had the same problem; now I replaced with the Traceback from the code that I gave here in my question.

Comment: Yes the error is internal to PyAudio, the goal is here to find where the bug is.

Comment: Two things:  1. I cannot reproduce this error on Linux, but of course I also do not have the specific sound card (ASIO).  2. The code in the line of the trace does not contain any hint on why a decoding is attempted.  It is only building a dict there.  That's strange.

Comment: `device_info.name` is a property. `PyUnicode_FromString(PaDeviceInfo.name)` is called when accessing the property. `PaDeviceInfo.name` is supposed to be UTF8 but apparently in this case it is not.

Comment: Some patches were posted to the PortAudio mailing list last year which fix some UTF8 device name issues on Windows. (search for "Unicode problems with Windows-build.") They are in the queue to be merged.

Comment: @RossBencina do you have an idea of how I can solve this for PyAudio as well? I'm a bit new to this (I'm sill unable to compile Portaudio+PyAudio with ASIO+DS at the same time, there are too many steps, and I got too many things to troubleshoot ;) )

Comment: `UnicodeDecodeError` is sadly quite common in Python. Following answer may apply to your specific case:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19706723/2419207

Comment: Also I'd suggest to tag your post with [`python-2.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-2.x) or [`python3.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python-3.x) depending on what version you are using. As handling encodings has changed a lot in Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#str-unicode and http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only successful solution found is :

- apply Tobias Erichsen'patch to PortAudio (as mentioned in @RossBencina's comment) that can be found here : https://www.assembla.com/spaces/portaudio/support/tickets/224-patch-for-windows-directsound-and-wmme-utf-8-device-names#/activity/ticket
- rebuild the whole thing

Many thanks to @cgohlke for having built new ready-to-use installers :
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

Answer (score 5):

The error 'invalid continuation byte' makes me think that the text is corrupt for that particular index.

If you're able to modify the pyaudio.py file (or get the pyaudio.py file to return just the name), you might be able to try handle the UTF-8 decoding yourself by using 'Unicode Dammit'.  It pretty much takes a best guess at what the encoding can be.  Here's a link to their tutorial (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit)

I think the code would look just like the tutorial:

```
from bs4 import UnicodeDammit

dammit = UnicodeDammit(audiodevicename)
print(dammit.unicode_markup) ## Wéird Device Name!
```

Comment: Hell I have no idea if that answer is going to help OP, but +1 for mentioning this library I had no idea about. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

I've forked pyAudio and modified https://github.com/joelewis/PyAudio/blob/master/src/_portaudiomodule.c code to use

```
PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault
```

instead of

```
 PyUnicode_FromString
```

which likely might solve the unicode issue. 
See if you could find it helpful.

fork:
https://github.com/joelewis/PyAudio/

Answer (score 0):

I think the clue here is

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte`

For whatever reason something returned by `get_device_info_by_index()`  (probably the `name` field) contains the byte `0xe9` which, if you are interpreting the string of bytes as UTF8, signifies a "continuation byte". This means that it expects some valid bytes to follow the `0xe9`. *valid bytes* means some sequence of bytes that constitutes a legitimate UTF8 character. E.g.

http://hexutf8.com/?q=e981a8

uses `0xe9` with some valid *continuation bytes*.